# Does anyone track number of sff novels translated to English each year?

Tags: awards

I recently learned of the Science Fiction and Fantasy Translation awards given this year at Eurocon in Stockholm. My question is how many Sff novels are translated into English  yearly? Does Locus magazine have this kind of information?

Awards: http://www.sfftawards.org/

Answer (score 2):

sfftawards.org has got posted [this](http://www.sfftawards.org/?p=202), it's from a couple of years ago:

> There’s some big news from Amazon today. They are launching a new
>   imprint, AmazonCrossing, that is dedicated to publishing works
>   translated into English.

Maybe Amazon has got an update record of those translations. Certainly it would be the first place to publish if I were to translate some SF title of my onw to english.

Answer (score 2):

Locus magazine includes at least some of it. For this year, for example, go to their [2012 Directory page](http://www.locusmag.com/Monitor/2012/Directory1.html) and use your browser to search the page for "translate". I only see 8, but many seem quite interesting.